# Play Media using URL in Android using Media

Tags: android, url, uri, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play music from URL with Media Player but getting error in playing it

```
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    try {

        mp.setDataSource(url[0]);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

i have also tried to use with URI

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url[0]);
        mp.setDataSource(context,uri);
        mp.prepare();
```

And also tried using  mp.prepareAsync(); method

But then also getting this type of error and media not playing

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1675)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1505)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1422)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1101)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1073)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1001)
    at com.tuwy.Dailog.DialogClass.showAudioDialog(DialogClass.java:272)
```

and getting this also

```
W/AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
V/AudioTrack: pause(2131): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE
I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: `mp.setDataSource(url[0]);` You have any idea what url[0] value is? We dont. We dont know what you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and this code solved my problem

i have used another thread to play music from url...

```
    final Handler handler =new Handler();

    final Thread audioThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(url[0]);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, myUri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                                mediaPlayer.pause();
                            } else {
                                if (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 0)
                                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

** url[0] means your music url and btnplaypause is the button to play and pause audio

Hope this will solve your problem too ...

Comment: Yes this really worked but when restarting music it starts from beginning

Comment: if you want music start from where you left remove these 2 lines ---
if (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 0)
mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);

Answer (score 0):

try to  parse the url into Uri.parse(url), that might work.